# HazelCast and SpringBoot Cache

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm looking integrate Hazelcast into my application..

My requirement is loading all the data into cache and fetching from cache..

I have two options.

1)Hazelcast  IMap<Key,Value> method.

2)Since I'm using spring-boot so Can I go with (@Cacheable/@CacheEvict).

Can I get some suggestion on this..

Thank you in Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both options are fine and you can use the one you prefer. I'd favor:

- using IMap directly if you want better performance (you don't need to use Spring layer to just insert values into cache)
- using Spring Abstraction if you want to be independent of the cache provider (for example, you may have a use case to change Hazelcast to something else)